# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d006d

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, illegalargumentexception

I want to add two fragments when the device is tablet(landscape). But i get the next Error:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d006d (com.example.placesearch1:id/container2) for fragment FragMap

I created two layouts : main_activity(**for phone**):

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    </FrameLayout>
```

and main_activity (**for tablet landscape** - activity_main.xml(sw600dp-land) :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have RecycleView of places(main_activity layout in container1). When i click the item, i get an latitude and longitude of a place and pass the values with bundle to Map fragment and put the map into one of the containers : if device is phone then in container1, but if device is tablet then in container2.

If the device is phone it works perfectly, but if the device is tablet, then i get an error.

in GetPlace method :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putDouble("lat", place.getLat());
        bundle.putDouble("lng", place.getLng());
        FragMap fragMap = new FragMap();
        fragMap.setArguments(bundle);

        if(getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTab)) {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container1, new ListFragment())
           .replace(R.id.container2, fragMap)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();


        }
        else {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container1, fragMap)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually when you are designing the `xml` for phone or tablet the file should be same and also in both `xml` the content should be same. But here in your case for phone there is only one `framelayout` but for tablet why two `framelayout`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from GetPlace method

```
 .replace(R.id.container1, new ListFragment())
```